# reading metadata columns after itemadded event is triggered

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

am working on a event receiver wherein i need to read a  look up column from the doc lib, the event receiver is fired correctly, [ itemadded eventhandler]  when i uploaded a  document from my custom web part.

after document is added into the document library along with few metadata columns which contains lookup column, spfield choice, single line of text etc.. i have to read these columns and perform another logic.

but i am not able to read the lookup column and other columns.

can any one point me, whats i was missing . when i debugged the code,

```
if(mitem["mylookupcolumn"]  != null ) //here it throws object reference  error 

{ // my  logic }

 if (singleItem.Fields[mylookupcolumnname] is SPFieldLookup)
                {

                    SPFieldLookupValue spfieldLookUpValue = newSPFieldLookupValue(singleItem[mylookupcolumnname] as string);  /// it thros the //error object reference error

                  selectedValue = spfieldLookUpValue.LookupValue.ToString();
                }
```

help is highly appreciated!

Comment: Check that you are using correct internal name of the field

Comment: If it throws an object reference error on this line:

> if(mitem["mylookupcolumn"]  != null ) //here it throws object reference  error 

this means your mitem object is null. Can you show us the rest of the code ?

Comment: the issue is resolved now. i have created a new sp project with itemupdated event handler and  added synchronization  as synchronous in the elements.xml file. i should not use itemadded event handler for the doclib's metadata manipulation.     thanks all, for your replies.